# How to fix error "jsx element class doesnt support attributes because it doesnt have a 'props' property using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have the code like below,

```
const Function = () => {
    const renderLabel = (
        <>
            <Text mr={2}>Event forwarding</Text> //error here
            <Tooltip
                overlay="some tooltip"
            >
                <span>
                    <Icon />
                </span>
           </Tooltip>
       </>
   );


   return (
       <FormField label={renderLabel}>
           {({ field, form }: FieldProps) => (
               <Switch />
           )}
        </>
   );
```

}

I am not sure how to fix this error " jsx element class doesnt support attributes because it doesnt have a 'props"

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: What part of that code gives you that error? Or are you getting it elsewhere when you try to use `Function`? (Side note: I **strongly** recommend not declaring something called `Function`, as there's a built-in global called `Function`.)

Comment: it gives me error in the renderLabel method on line containing <Text> component. i have tried to remove that component but still gives error on line <Tooltip> If i remove <Text> and <Tooltip> components there is no error. thanks for example purpose i have used name "Function"

Comment: To improve the question, please use the "edit" link on the question rather than trying to post code in comments. (I do now see your pseudo-comment in the code, but better to state it clearly in the question.)

Comment: Does the `Text` component have a `mr` property? Does `Tooltip` have an `overlay` property?

Comment: yes those components have those properties

Comment: now i realised that i dint import one of these components and it was accessing some default components. thanks